# как посмотреть js код элемента?

Tags: javascript

В браузере в панели разработчика можно выделить элемент и посмотреть его html код и css стили [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как посмотреть JavaScript код выделенного элемента?

Answer (score 1):

Код JS можно посмотреть на вкладке "Источники" (для хрома). Только там код не выделенного элемента будет, а вообще весь код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А вот в *Firefox* можно посмотреть все события, которые прикреплены на элемент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Comment: Спасибо, только что-то скачал последний firefox (98.0.2)и он не отображает в инспекторе никакие события(( Я даже кнопку выделил ,которая вызывает диалоговое окно, и значка события нет. Может от того что к fancybox привязана библиотеки